# Data structure that owns objects and returns IDs for them

Tags: c++, data-structures, associative-array

I need a data structure that manages integer IDs for `T` objects (typically `std::string`). It
should support getting the ID for some object and, vice versa, get the object for some ID:

```
// if object not seen before: copies and stores object and returns
// new ID, otherwise just returns its ID
int Add(const T& obj);

// if obj not found: returns some specified `NotFound` ID,
// otherwise just returns its ID
int GetId(const T& obj);

// if id not contained: throws exception, 
// otherwise returns associated object
const T& GetObj(int id)
```

It should also own all those `T` objects, so internally it allocates new objects, stores them and deletes them in the destructor.

Any comments? How would you implement that?

I am using these two containers inside; every object pointer is stored in both:

```
// quickly retrieve the ID
std::map<const T*, int, CompareByValue> Obj2IdMap;
// quickly retrieve the object, given an ID
std::vector<const T*> Id2ObjMap;
```

Are there any other data structures that might help? Or is this whole object ID manager already available in some library?

Comment: For first question it seems you compulsorily need RAII. For the second question hash_map could be another option !!

Answer (score 1):

> It should also own all those T
>   objects, so internally it allocates
>   new objects, stores them and deletes
>   them in the destructor.
>
> Any comments? How would you implement
>   that?

I would use [boost shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) to manage the objects.

> Are there any other data structures
>   that might help? Or is this whole
>   object ID manager already available in
>   some library?

Check this Stack Overflow thread: [Using STL containers for multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858306/using-stl-containers-for-multiple-keys). I think thats a good alternative solution for your problem although, to be honest, I have used your very same approach in lots of projects too.

Comment: They recommend Boost.MultiIndex. That makes sense (although it looks slightly intimidating ...).